# Drawing on caption bar in MFC

Tags: mfc

I want to put some controls on the caption bar of a dialog box. One possible solutions of this is ,I simply remove caption bar from the dialog and draw my own caption Bar.

But if I draw my own caption bar ,the look of caption bar would not change according to the theme of window . And I also would have to take pain of drawing close ,minimize and maximize btns.

so I want to ask is it possible to draw the controls on caption bar which can be custom buttons or any other window, without drawing the whole caption bar.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No doubt you could do this but it's almost surely a really bad idea to do so.  UI works well when it is predictable and consistent.  How will you deal with different OS versions, themed/unthemed, future versions of the OS that may be quite different in the way they paint non-client regions.  Programs that do their own thing are generally annoying because of it, for example iTunes, Safari, QuickTime for Windows which try to con you into believing that you are running on a Mac, or Firefox 4 with its bizarro menus.  My recommendation is to let the system draw the non-client area as nature intended, and to put your UI in the client area.

Comment: In other words you could add a toolbar to your dialog which has all the controls you want instead of messing with the caption bar.

Comment: I understand the argument of this answer, but please take a look at Office 2016 and Chrome, they are conforming to the OS look and feel but utilizing the toolbar differently or coloring it differently, it doesn't look alien to the OS

Comment: Right up until the point where the next version of the OS uses totally different theming. Something like a tabbed browser has little choice but to go custom because the system doesn't offer built in UI to do the job.